# How to load .wasm file in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webassembly

I have been trying to load a WebAssembly (.wasm) file - generated C++ code compiled to WebAssembly by Emscripten - in a React-Native app.

This is my code to fetch the .wasm file:

```
import fs from 'react-native-fs';

if (!global.WebAssembly) {
  global.WebAssembly = require('webassemblyjs');
}

const fetchWasm = async () => {
  const wasm = await fetch(`${fs.MainBundlePath}/calculator.wasm`);

  console.log(wasm);
  // Returns: Response {type: "default", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}

  const mod = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(wasm);

  console.log(mod);
  // Throws: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': An argument must be provided, which must be a Response or Promise<Response> object
};
```

I tried everything in the Google search results I could find, but nothing worked so far. Unfortunately, the most related questions were unanswered.

Is there anyone who knows what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiateStreaming) WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming, returns a promise. In order to retrieve its output i think you need to add a `.then()`

Comment: I use the await to get the result of the Promise and assign it to the 'mod' variable.

Comment: Try: `const mod = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(wasm).then(mod => console.log(mod));`

Comment: Just a wild guess because I think I've ran into a similar issue before. I think your `wasm` variable is not an actual object, otherwise `console.log` would not append "Response" to the beginning. You probably need to use `JSON.parse(wasm)`.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: have you added wasm in `assetExts` of metro.config.js?

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing to be aware when wanting to load wasm :

Your webserver must report .wasm mime type as "application/wasm" , otherwise you won't be able loading it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume still React-native JS runtime JSC still not support WebAssembly in Android build
the issue is still open
`https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts/issues/113`

Another way is to use Webview but I assume it is not  you are expecting.
https://github.com/ExodusMovement/react-native-wasm

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-webassembly](https://github.com/cawfree/react-native-webassembly) looks promising:

> This package enables WebAssembly for React Native powered by C++ TurboModules and Wasm3, a fast and universal WebAssembly runtime.